# Proof if $AB = BA$ is not verified, then $AB$ is not symmetric.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

They ask me the following question:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two symmetric matrices of the same order, show that if
>   $AB = BA$ is not verified, then $AB$ is not symmetric.

I have tried the following but I do not know if it is correct:

if $AB \neq BA \Rightarrow (AB)^t = B^tA^t = BA \neq AB$

Comment: Assume that AB is symmetric. What happens?

Comment: It seems like it might be easiest to show that $AB = BA$ implies that $AB$ is symmetric, which is equivalent (by contraposition) to what you want to show.

Comment: Yes, it's correct.